# Is this transformation possible with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe that contains the columns:

| Area | Item | Unit | Y2000 | Y2001 | Y2002 |

The composite key here would be the Area and Item. Item, in this case, is what is being measured for the area. Unit is the unit of what is being measured. The following are the values for each year.

I want to make it so the table is structured like:

| Area | Item | Unit | Year | Value |

So now there is a row for each year and the value column contains what was in the area's item for that year

**example:**

- Want to turn:

Antigua and Barbuda | Average dietary energy supply adequacy | % | NaN | 90 | 80 |

- into:

Antigua and Barbuda | Average dietary energy supply adequacy | % | 2000 | NaN |

Antigua and Barbuda | Average dietary energy supply adequacy | % | 2001 | 90  |

Antigua and Barbuda | Average dietary energy supply adequacy | % | 2002 | 80  |

I am quite new to pandas and was trying to get this to work with pivot, but could not come up with anything useful. I can do this manually with for loops, but I figured I would ask some more experienced pandas users what they thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt):

```py
out = df.melt(id_vars=["Area", "Item", "Unit"], var_name="Year")
out.Year = out.Year.str.strip("Y").astype(int)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                  Area                                    Item Unit  Year  value
0  Antigua and Barbuda  Average dietary energy supply adequacy    %  2000    NaN
1  Antigua and Barbuda  Average dietary energy supply adequacy    %  2001   90.0
2  Antigua and Barbuda  Average dietary energy supply adequacy    %  2002   80.0
```

Comment: This does it! Thanks for your help I would've never found this on my own.